# Can we mail a specific person

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Rather than asking questions openly?

Say a person has an interesting comment and you want to know more. We don't have "pm" like other forums do we?

Answer (score 4):

No. Generally speaking, there are no private communications on Stack Exchange, by design. See [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/179) for a lot more detail.

I particularly like this aspect of the site architecture because it contributes to this being a [safe community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1011/2) for minors to participate in.